# Deleted file generate exception while zipping in C++/CLI with ZipFile::CreateFromDirectory()?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, visual-studio-2019, zip

I'm working in C++/CLI with .NET 4.5.2 on Win10. I develop with VS2019 16.1.6 (I know...)

I'm currently debugging an app where the following operations are done:

1. A *sentinel* LOCK file is created in a given directory.
2. Some job is done.
3. The *sentinel* file LOCK is deleted.
4. Then `System::IO::Compression::ZipFile::CreateFromDirectory()` is called. *Note that it works perfectly most of the time.*

In the bug, when `CreateFromDirectory` is called, an IOException is thrown telling "*The process cannot access the file ... LOCK because it is being used by another process.*"

At this point, the *sentinel* file LOCK is assumed to be deleted. Actually I deleted it using this code:

```
System::IO::File::Delete( "LOCK" );

while ( System::IO::File::Exists( "LOCK" )
{
    System::Threading::Thread::Sleep( 20 );
}
```

I use this snippet because I already had problem with "not really deleted" file (while this problem never occurs when stepping in debug because of the much larger delays...) But now, I don't know...

My hypothesis is the following:

1. When `CreateFromDirectory()`begins its job, the *sentinel* file still exists in some place (???) and is listed by the method.
2. When it is time to compress it (or during compression), it is actually deleted. Thus the exception...

So my questions are:

1. Is my hypothesis possible?
2. Is there a way to protect the execution (the workflow) from this?
3. Any other idea?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Anti-malware is the usual trouble-maker, it often gets its underwear in a bundle when an .exe file appears from seemingly nowhere.  Add an exclusion for your build directory.  Do keep in mind that creating a file in the same directory as the .exe is not possible when you deploy correctly, there are much better ways to negotiate locks between processes.

Comment: @HansPassant Well actually the LOCK file and the files to be zipped are created in temp folder and in some places like `<username>\AppData\Local\...`. However I understand your point. But I don't have access to end user anti-malware settings... Should I proceed with my code in a loop like `do{ try{ } catch{} } while( failed);`???

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the comment from @HansPassant helped me to find the problem. But it was not an anti-malware that locked the file LOCK but rather the application itself. Simple workflow problem after all... The file, created by a `FileStream` was never closed/disposed/deleted in a particular workflow path and this one lead to the crash.

Thanks for your comment.